# In C#, how many bytes does a System.Device.Location.GeoCoordinate use?

Tags: c#, class, memory, serialization

The class is not serializable.  I made a test console app where it ONLY added 
10^7 new GeoCoordinates(1,1) to a List, and the resulting memory usage of the app was 735 MB in windows.

I guess the number of bytes is 72 bytes?

Comment: Apparently, for your runtime, bitness and phase of the moon, it is. These things [vary for managed objects](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cbrumme/2003/04/15/size-of-a-managed-object/), so measuring effective memory usage *is* the appropriate way.

Comment: Take a look at [Hans Passant's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3362736) to [How do I check the number of bytes consumed by a structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3361986), and also look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28514434) to [What is the size of a boolean In C#? Does it really take 4-bytes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28514373).  Basically the size of a structure is intentionally obscured, but measuring the size of a large array of them might be the most accurate approximation.

Comment: @dbc The problem is that it is a class, not a struct.

Comment: @PatrickHofman - Ah thank you.  That makes it even less well defined then.

Comment: Indeed, hence the duplicate @dbc